# xgboost with categorical data - parser error

Tags: python, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I'm trying to train an XGBoost model which has also categorical variable. I'd like to avoid onehot encoding and I saw it is now possible using `enable_categorical=True`. I formatted my dataframe but when I try to generate the `DMatrix` I get the error below. I also attach a very simple example that recapitulate the error.

```
import xgboost as xgb
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame({'out': ["a","b"],'features': [np.array(["house","horse","something", "NA" ]), np.array(["house","NA","NA", "NA" ]) ]})

X_train = test['features'].to_json()
y_train = test['out'].to_json()

xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
```

Then I get this warning/error:

```
[14:32:11] WARNING: ../src/data/data.cc:868: No format parameter is provided in input uri.  Choosing default parser in dmlc-core.  Consider providing a uri parameter like: filename?format=csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 620, in inner_f
    return func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 743, in __init__
    handle, feature_names, feature_types = dispatch_data_backend(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/data.py", line 964, in dispatch_data_backend
    return _from_uri(data, missing, feature_names, feature_types)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/data.py", line 880, in _from_uri
    _check_call(_LIB.XGDMatrixCreateFromFile(c_str(data),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 279, in _check_call
    raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [14:32:11] ../src/data/data.cc:874: Encountered parser error:
[14:32:11] ../dmlc-core/src/io/local_filesys.cc:86: LocalFileSystem.GetPathInfo: {"0":["house","horse","something","NA"],"1":["house","NA","NA","NA"]} error: No such file or directory
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x83a293) [0x7f01eb5ea293]
  [bt] (1) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x83c13c) [0x7f01eb5ec13c]
  [bt] (2) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x822929) [0x7f01eb5d2929]
  [bt] (3) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x822e1e) [0x7f01eb5d2e1e]
  [bt] (4) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x812ca6) [0x7f01eb5c2ca6]
  [bt] (5) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x81312e) [0x7f01eb5c312e]
  [bt] (6) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x7f2210) [0x7f01eb5a2210]
  [bt] (7) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x7d4141) [0x7f01eb584141]
  [bt] (8) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x214294) [0x7f01eafc4294]


Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x20b233) [0x7f01eafbb233]
  [bt] (1) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0xfc7ad) [0x7f01eaeac7ad]
  [bt] (2) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(XGDMatrixCreateFromFile+0xdf) [0x7f01eaef762f]
  [bt] (3) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7(+0x6d1d) [0x7f0248f58d1d]
  [bt] (4) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7(+0x6289) [0x7f0248f58289]
  [bt] (5) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_ctypes_callproc+0x336) [0x7f0248f75477]
  [bt] (6) /usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0xae9e) [0x7f0248f70e9e]
  [bt] (7) /usr/local/bin/../lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0(_PyObject_MakeTpCall+0x87) [0x7f024f004437]
  [bt] (8) /usr/local/bin/../lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x41f7) [0x7f024f031d07]
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how it can be solved? Is the format ok?

```
-----
numpy               1.23.5
pandas              2.0.2
xgboost             1.7.5
-----
Python 3.8.16 (default, May 23 2023, 14:26:40) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
Linux-5.10.104-linuxkit-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5
-----
```

EDIT:
I didn't give much context in my original question, but I'd prefer not to split `features` into different columns because of the data itself. The reason for this is that the way `features` appears is not ordered, so I could have the same feature in column1 at times and columnN in other cases.
I imagined this problem could be overcome if all the features are part of the same array.
Could something similar could be achieved for categorical values?
I tried
`X_train = np.vstack(test['features'].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category') ))`
but then I get the error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'chain'` in my DMatrix.
Is training on an array something achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` parameter can take one of the following:

- os.PathLike
- string (path from file)
- numpy.array
- scipy.sparse
- pd.DataFrame
- dt.Frame
- cudf.DataFrame
- cupy.array
- dlpack

but not a JSON string.

So you have to pass a DataFrame or a Numpy array. However you have to convert as numeric (or category). Try something like:

```
X_train = (pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(test['features']))
             .replace('NA', np.nan)
             .add_prefix('feat_')
             .apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]))
y_train = pd.factorize(test['out'])[0]

dmat = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
```

Output:

```
>>> dmat
<xgboost.core.DMatrix at 0x7f225b6483d0>

>>> X_train
   feat0  feat1  feat2  feat3
0      0      0      0     -1
1      0     -1     -1     -1

>>> y_train
array([0, 1])
```

EDIT:

> I'd prefer not to split features into different columns because of the data itself. The reason for this is that the way features appears is not ordered, so I could have the same feature in column1 at times and columnN in other cases

`XGBoost` is a Decision-Tree algorithm so you need columns. Instead of `pd.factorize`, you can use `pd.get_dummies`:

```
X_train = (pd.get_dummies(test['features'].explode()
             .loc[lambda x: x != 'NA']).astype(int)
             .groupby(level=0).max())
print(X_train)

# Output
   horse  house  something
0      1      1          1
1      0      1          0
```

Comment: Thanks, Corralien. Your code worked. 
I guess I didn't give much context in the original question. I edited it to add some more info on why I'd need to keep the features column in an array-like structure. Would you be able to help?

Comment: Or if XGboost cannot coop with lists, could you suggest any other algorithm?

Comment: I updated my answer related to your edit. If you use `pd.get_dummies`, regardless of the order of your features, your dataframe will always be consistent. Let me know if it's worked (or not) :)